# Append gif animations through php

Tags: php, gif

**PROBLEM**
I'd like my PHP script to call 3 animated gifs from a selection and then append them and then output.

I'm NOT looking for the code (necessarily) but more of an idea as to where I can find more information. While I've been looking at phpmanual,imagick, various video turorials  and other things nothing really covers...

A) If it's possible

and of course I'd like to know...

B) How to start

**FOR EXAMPLE**
I have on file 10 cartoon.gifs (animated).
The php asks for gif files 1, 7, 10 (to be played in that order)

gif 1 = man starts to cross street

gif 7 = man narrowly misses truck

gif 10 = man reaches other side

Is there a way I can create one animation?

**Nota bene**
It is possible that i preset each gif to last X seconds for programming code purposes.

Comment: There is JS browser based GIF generator http://mothereffinganimatedgif.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by this class:
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3163-PHP-Generate-GIF-animations-from-a-set-of-GIF-images.html

Comment: Thanks nice one.This looks like the way to go, it is outside my PHP comfort zone as now I have to study OOP a little... but learning in necessity is often best!!!